# Two-way MANOVA vs. two-way ANOVA on a composite variable

Tags: anova, biostatistics, manova

Is using a 2 way MANOVA to check whether height and weight differ across age groups and gender, the same as using a 2 way ANOVA to check whether BMI (wt in kg/ht in m$^2$) differ across age groups and gender?

Comment: Adding on to what @amoeba said: you should also consider *upvoting* answers that you like (whether or not you accept them, whether or not you asked the original question) by clicking the up arrow to the top left of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No. The manova tests the bivariate effects, and is based only on **linear** functions thereof; whereas the BMI measure is a nonlinear function of those two responses. Even if BMI were linear, you'd be restricting the comparison to a 1-dimensional subspace of the two dimensions in your data.

Comment: Which sounds sensible?

Comment: Both, in their own context. BMI is well understood and is an easier "sell" in discussing your analysis. But if the groups differ in a way substantially different than the BMI, the manova will pick up on that (provided it is linear). Another idea is to take logs. Note that log BMI = log wt - 2*log ht, so if you do the multivariate analysis on the logged responses, and see that the coefficients are more-or-less proportional to 1 and -2, that'd indicate that BMI is the big player and you could simplify. The log scale may make the diagnostics look better too.

Comment: How do I interpret the result after log transformation?

Comment: Important caveat is that statistical inferences (frequentist hypothesis testing, or confidence intervals) on transformed variables **do not** apply to statistical inferences on untransformed variables, because $f(\sigma^{2}_{x}) \ne \sigma^{2}_{f(x)}$.

Comment: Your last sentence (in the preceding comment) is a falsehood, and is why I made my point: back transformation **does not work for *inference* because one cannot validly back transform the variance term(s) upon which the inference in the transformed variable(s) is based**.

Comment: Do you mean to say that log transformation doesn't give the true inference with respect to the original variables? Should I go with 2 way MANOVA rather than the one with BMI?

Comment: @Alexis, I do not understand how your caveat applies to this particular case. What Russ suggested, is to do MANOVA on log-transformed height and weight, then look at what direction yields maximal discriminability (equivalently, use LDA to find first discriminant axis), and compare coefficients to 1 and -2 assumed by BMI. First, such an analysis would not yield any uncertainties on these coefficients (as far as I know). Second, even if it did, why would one consider transforming them back and what could that even mean?

Comment: @amoeba My point is that inference about a transformed variable, like ln(BMI) does not apply to the untransformed variable, like BMI. Simple example: conduct a *t* test of difference for ln(BMI), and reject the null hypothesis to conclude that ln(BMI) is different in group A vs B. You **cannot** validly conclude that BMI (untransformed) is different between groups, because $\sigma^{2}_{ln(BMI)} \ne ln(\sigma^{2}_{BMI})$ and therefore **both** *t* statistic values **and** CIs can give different inferences from the transformed case. This also applies to inference in your analysis.

Comment: @Alexis: I understand your example, but this is mainly because the assumption of normality made by t-test cannot be valid for both x and ln(x). And non-parametric tests such as ranksum will yield the same outcome in both cases. However, this does relate to the current discussion, because MANOVA obviously does rely on normality as well...

Comment: The nonparametric test issue is a good point. But my point is not simply because of an assumption of normality. Non-monotonic transformations will alter rank ordering, and thus nonparametric inferences made about so-transformed data will not apply to untransformed data.

Comment: People transform data **all the time**. Yes, it's true that the inference made isn't exactly equivalent to one made on the original scale. But that's the whole point. You're making an inference on a parameter, not on the measurements. An inference comparing the mean log BMI for two groups is in fact an inference on the ratio of the geometric means of the two groups. That's a different framework, but there's nothing invalid about making inferences about geometric means.